# Not able to call sqlsrv_connect function

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2012, wamp

I am using:

- Windows Server 2012
- WAMP with PHP 5.4.12
- Microsoft SQL Server 2012

I have downloaded the corresponding `php_54_ts.dll` and `php_pdo_54_ts.dll` and placed them in extension folder in `wamp\bin\php`, but still get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\wamp\www\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php on line 76.
```

Comment: We need more information that what you have provided. What are you doing? What is the code that is failing (yes, we see you are calling sqlsrv_connect on line 76)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the sqlsrv extension in your php config?

You need to have:
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll

in your php.ini file before you can use the extension.